# Concept of relative speed

Tags: kinematics, velocity

I am traveling on a train running at a speed of 100mph. If from the train I shoot a ball at a speed of 100mph in opposite direction then what would be the speed of the ball with respect to a person standing outside the train,  <strike>given that I shoot the ball as soon as the person standing out comes in parallel to my position in the train.</strike>

Comment: Well what do you think?

Answer (score 4):

The Ball will fall at that place and you will move away so you will think that ball is moving at 100 mph while the guy standing outside will measure the ball velocity as zero.